# Should Sheared Sheep Sprout Surplus Stuff?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

While playing minecraft on Xbox, I have set up a sheep farm to harvest coloured wool. It has been some time since I sheared the lot of them, and yet, they are all still bald (not totally bald, but spotty, I guess).

According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep#Behavior), a sheep that eats grass will regrow its wool, allowing it to be sheared again. I have not witnessed this behaviour yet. However, after reading the whole page I found that in earlier versions of minecraft, the sheep did not eat grass nor regrow wool.

I was unable to find anything on the [Xbox Version page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition_version_history) that indicates the status of this feature.

My question is this: Will my sheep regrow their wool, or will I need to initiate a breeding program to harvest a continual supply of wool?

Comment: Nice title :-) Though, what about "Should Sheared Sheep Sprout Surplus Stuff"?

Comment: @Zommuter, I like it. Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Xbox edition is behind in updates from the PC version, it is comparable to [version 1.0.1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition_version_history#1.3) (PCs are on 1.4.7 as of the time of this post).  It seems that for the most recent version on the 360, sheep will not eat grass nor will they grow their wool again.

You'll have to start up a big breeding bay you were talking about for the sheep after all.

Comment: Although it should be noted that if you are after coloured wool, you can get multiple pieces by dyeing the **sheep** and then shearing them, instead of dyeing the wool after you've shorn them. You may not need that big of a sheep farm if you do this

Comment: @Robotnik, even if I shear the sheep, I get 1-3 wool and a bald sheep. By breeding sheep, I can get a limitless supply of wool - the colour is randomly selected from one of the parents.

Comment: @ChargingPun - true, and the colour counts even if the sheep is shorn when breeding I'm pretty sure. I just meant if you were after large quantities of coloured wool, its easier to colour the sheep, not the wool after you've shorn it